# python mechanize submitting form kicks me back to root

Tags: python, forms, cookies, submit, mechanize

i have a mechanize python script written for submitting forms to inquire drug information. and when i run it, it gives me no error message, but when i look at the response, it's not what I see on my browser view-source page. i checked the urls after the submission:

here's what I got:

http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm

here's addresses I'm supposed to get:

http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.DrugDetails

I see that the second url does not contain my query text, does that mean i need cookies? if so, how?

this is my code snippet:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
....
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/6.0 (X11; U; i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 OS X 10.2 Firefox/3.0.1')]

fda_url2 = 'http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.Addlsearch_drug_name'

print br.open(fda_url2).geturl()


for f in br.forms():
   print 'this is a form'
   print f

br.select_form('searchoptionB')
br.form['ApplNo'] = '018780'
html = br.submit(name = 'Search_Button')

print html.geturl()
```

the print form  output was:

```
<searchoptionB POST http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(fuseaction=Search.SearchAction) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(SearchType=AddlSearch) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(SearchOption=B) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(ApplNo=)>
  <SubmitControl(Search_Button=Submit) (readonly)>
  <SubmitControl(clearcriteria=Clear) (readonly)>>
```

sorry for the long post ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD** Regarding your comment. Here's my test file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import mechanize
import cookielib

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/6.0 (X11; U; i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 OS X 10.2 Firefox/3.0.1')]

fda_url2 = 'http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.Addlsearch_drug_name'

print br.open(fda_url2).geturl()


for f in br.forms():
   print 'this is a form'
   print f

br.select_form('searchoptionB')
br.form['ApplNo'] = '018780'
html = br.submit()

print br.response().read()
```

And this is what I get when running it:

```
$ ./test.py  | grep HUM
            <td valign="top" class="product_table" height="24"><a href="index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.Overview&DrugName=HUMULIN%20R">
 HUMULIN R
 INSULIN RECOMBINANT HUMAN
            <td valign="top" class="product_table" height="24"><a href="index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.Overview&DrugName=HUMULIN%20R%20PEN">
 HUMULIN R PEN
 INSULIN RECOMBINANT HUMAN
```

Maybe you've somehow changed your script or query a different page?

---

Have you tried to submit this form in a browser?

If I navigate to [this URL](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.Addlsearch_drug_name), fill in "Option B" with "018780" and hit "Submit", the browser indeed redirects me to http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm, which contains the search results.

Try adding this to the end of your code snippet:

```
print br.response().read()
```

This will output the HTML of the page, and it does contain search results as expected.

> I see that the second url does not contain my query text, does that mean i need cookies? if so, how?

This form is sent via POST, and in this case all parameters are embedded in request body (RFC 2616).

Comment: i rechecked and the response indeed is there, but i couldn't see it before because it was cut off in the middle, like the page stopped loading abruptly, and the link to the drug page displayed first, but the drug name couldn't make it. after i navigate to this link, this time the html response is fully loaded, but the contents are different from what i see in chrome. you can find 'HUM' in chrome source of this page, but not in mechanize. the link is: http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.Overview&DrugName=HUMULIN%20R

Comment: i've sorted the first part out by relaxing my wait time.but after i got the drug name and opened drug detail link,the response content is wrong.link: http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.Overview&DrugName=HUMULIN%20R. this is what should come up:
`<td width="20%" valign="top" height="32" class="product_table">INJECTABLE; INJECTION&nbsp;</td>
   <td width="20%" valign="top" height="32" class="product_table">500 UNITS/ML&nbsp;</td>
   <td width="20%" valign="top" height="32" class="product_table">Prescription</td>
`
what u think caused the problem?

Comment: `'http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.Overview&DrugName=HUMULIN%20R`

Comment: I meant a snippet of Python code that doesn't behave as expected :-)

Comment: I just found my bug, all was for a browser handler misconfiguration. Thank you so so much!!!